# Fancybox won't show targeted div

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've got a list of items with descriptions. In the list I show a snippet of the description with an anchor tag with a generated href. Below the anchor tag is a hidden div with the full description in it that I want to appear in the fancybox.:

```
<ul id="op_list">
   <cfloop query="session.data">
    <li><p class="op_desc"><cfoutput>#Mid(title, 1, 26 )#</cfoutput>&hellip; 
      <a class="viewitem" href="listings.cfm#item<cfoutput>#item_id#</cfoutput>">More Info</a></p>
                <div style="display:none;">
                    <div id="item<cfoutput>#item_id#</cfoutput>">
                    <h2><cfoutput>#title#</cfoutput></h2>
                    <p><cfoutput>#description#</cfoutput></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </li>
    </cfloop>
</ul>
```

Then I've got a some jQuery (inside the document.ready() function) that should fire a fancybox with the full item description but, it won't fire the fancybox. Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.viewitem').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var theDiv = '#' + this.hash.substr(1);
    alert(theDiv);
    $(theDiv).fancybox({
        'titleShow'  : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
        });
});
```

Where am I going wrong here. I can get the fancybox to fire if I had code it to do so, so I know fancybox is connected and working fine. Also, the alert generates the appropriate code as well, so I know that works too.

What incredibly simple thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in how I was forming the jQuery fancybox function. Here's the correct code...

```
$('.viewitem').live('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
        'href' : '#' + this.hash.substr(1)
    });     
    return false;
});
```